# Resize the size of the cells in a table

Tags: html, size, cell

I need a JavaScript function that would allow me to resize the cells of a line of each table in an HTML file so that the global size of the line is equal to the declared size of the table. The goal is to have the dimensions to pass to PdfMake in the form of data-pdfmake widths: [cellWidths].

Example:

- declared table size = 538.6
- size of each cell in the 1st row = 129.55
- 4 cells per line so 129.55 * 4 = 518.2
- Difference = 538.6 - 518.2 = 20.4
  It is thus necessary to change the size of each cell by 20.4/4 = 5.1 so 129.55 + 5.1 = 124.45 and this for all the lines of all the tables of the html.

Here are the portions of code that I currently have:

```js
function fnProcessTables() {
  var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
  for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) { 
    var t = tables [i];
    // find 1st row
    var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    if (rows && rows.length > 0) {
      var tr = rows [0];
      // row cells
      var cells = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");
      // find cell widths and store them as "w1,w2...,wN"
      var cellWidths = "";
      for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
        var td = cells [j];

        var w = parseFloat(td.style.width);

        if (cellWidths) {
          cellWidths = cellWidths + ','
        }
        cellWidths = cellWidths + w.toString();
      }
      // add data-pdfmake attribute to the table: '{"widths":[w1,w2...,wN]}')
      t.setAttribute("data-pdfmake", '{"widths":[' + cellWidths + ']}');
    }
  }
};
```

and a sample table in my HTML:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0pt" style="width:**538.6**pt;border-collapse:collapse;">
<colgroup>
<col width="180" />
<col width="180" />
<col width="180" />
<col width="180" />
</colgroup>
<tr align="left" valign="top">
<td style="width:**129.55**pt; padding-right:1.8pt; padding-left:1.8pt; border-top: 1pt solid #000000; border-right: 1pt solid #000000; border-bottom: 1pt solid #000000; border-left: 1pt solid #000000;">
<p lang="fr-FR" style="text-align:right;text-indent:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;font-family:'Courier New';font-size:10pt;color:#000000;">1</p>
</td>
<td style="width:**129.55**pt; padding-right:1.8pt; padding-left:1.8pt; border-top: 1pt solid #000000; border-right: 1pt solid #000000; border-bottom: 1pt solid #000000; border-left: 1pt solid #000000;">
<p lang="fr-FR" style="text-align:right;text-indent:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;font-family:'Courier New';font-size:10pt;color:#000000;">2</p>
</td>
<td style="width:**129.55**pt; padding-right:1.8pt; padding-left:1.8pt; border-top: 1pt solid #000000; border-right: 1pt solid #000000; border-bottom: 1pt solid #000000; border-left: 1pt solid #000000;">
<p lang="fr-FR" style="text-align:right;text-indent:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;font-family:'Courier New';font-size:10pt;color:#000000;">3</p>
</td>
<td style="width:**129.55**pt; padding-right:1.8pt; padding-left:1.8pt; border-top: 1pt solid #000000; border-right: 1pt solid #000000; border-bottom: 1pt solid #000000; border-left: 1pt solid #000000;">
<p lang="fr-FR" style="text-align:right;text-indent:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;font-family:'Courier New';font-size:10pt;color:#000000;">4</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you have a table with a defined width in its `style`. For example:

```
<table style="width:538.6pt">
```

And you want the cells to have this width divided by the number of cells in a row. For example, instead of:

```
<tr>
  <td style="width:129.55pt">Cell 1</td>
  <td style="width:129.55pt">Cell 1</td>
  <td style="width:129.55pt">Cell 1</td>
  <td style="width:129.55pt">Cell 1</td>
<tr>
```

You want to have (tableWidth / nb of cells in row = 538.6 / 4 = 134.65):

```
<tr>
  <td style="width:134.65pt">Cell 1</td>
  <td style="width:134.65pt">Cell 2</td>
  <td style="width:134.65pt">Cell 3</td>
  <td style="width:134.65pt">Cell 4</td>
<tr>
```

Note – in your question you said:

> Difference = 538.6 - 518.2 = 20.4 It is thus necessary to change the size of each cell by 20.4/4 = 5.1 so 129.55 + 5.1 = 124.45

But 129.55 + 5.1 is not equal to 124.45, so you probably meant 129.55 + 5.1 = **134.65** (the same result as me)

**Your code is actually correct**. It will render:

```
<table style="width:538.6pt;border-collapse:collapse;" data-pdfmake="{&quot;widths&quot;:[129.55,129.55,129.55,129.55]}" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0pt">
```

When you pass it to [html-to-pdfmake playground](https://aymkdn.github.io/html-to-pdfmake/index.html), by disabling the [the `tableAutoSize`](https://github.com/Aymkdn/html-to-pdfmake#tableautosize) option (at the bottom right), it will return:

```
    "widths": [
      134.65,
      134.65,
      134.65,
      134.65
    ]
```

**Which is the expected behavior. So you're all set!**

However, if you want to use the option `tableAutoSize`, as described [in the documentation](https://github.com/Aymkdn/html-to-pdfmake#tableautosize), the script will use the `width` that is in the `style` attribute of each cells, and you won't need to do a `t.setAttribute("data-pdfmake", '{"widths":[' + cellWidths + ']}');`.

In the case you want to use this `tableAutoSize` option, [html-to-pdfmake](https://github.com/Aymkdn/html-to-pdfmake) will use the largest `width` for each cell. To avoid any issues with colspan cells, it's better to remove all `width` for each cells, and just apply the wanted width to the first's cells:

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) { 
  var t = tables[i];
  // find the width for the table in "style"
  var tableStyle = t.getAttribute("style");
  if (tableStyle && tableStyle.indexOf("width") > -1) {
    // search for the width's value
    var mtch = tableStyle.match(/width:(\d+(\.\d+)?)pt;?/);
    if (mtch) {
      // 'tableWidth' is the total width for the row that we want to apply
      var tableWidth = mtch[1];
      for (var r=0; r<t.rows.length; r++) {
        var cells = t.rows[r].getElementsByTagName('th');
        if (cells.length === 0) cells = t.rows[r].getElementsByTagName('td');
        // we assume the first row will always have the maximum number of cells
        // meaning there will never be any "colspan" in the first row
        if (r === 0) {
          // we have to divide the table's width by the number of cells
          var widthByCell = tableWidth / cells.length;
        }
        for (var c=0; c<cells.length; c++) {
          // remove the "width" in style because html-to-pdfmake will use this value when option tableAutoSize:true
          var style = cells[c].getAttribute("style") || "";
          // do we have a style?
          if (style.indexOf("width") > -1) {
            // remove the existing 'width' value
            style = style.replace(/width:\d+(\.\d+)?pt;?/g,"");
          }
          // if it's the first row, then we add the new width
          if (r === 0) {
            style += "width:"+widthByCell+"pt";
          }
          cells[c].setAttribute("style", style);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After applying this code, your row will look like the below – the original `width` value has been removed, and a new `width` has been applied:

```
<tr valign="top" align="left">
  <td style="[...some style...];width:134.65pt">
  <p style="text-align:right;text-indent:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;font-size:10pt;color:#000000;" lang="fr-FR">1</p>
  </td>
  <td style="[...some style...];width:134.65pt">
  <p style="text-align:right;text-indent:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;font-size:10pt;color:#000000;" lang="fr-FR">2</p>
  </td>
  <td style="[...some style...];width:134.65pt">
  <p style="text-align:right;text-indent:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;font-size:10pt;color:#000000;" lang="fr-FR">3</p>
  </td>
  <td style="[...some style...];width:134.65pt">
  <p style="text-align:right;text-indent:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;font-size:10pt;color:#000000;" lang="fr-FR">4</p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And `html-to-pdfmake` will render the `widths` for you:

```
    "widths": [
      134.65,
      134.65,
      134.65,
      134.65
    ]
```

So it depends if you use the `tableAutoSize` option or not :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Aymeric but I don't have good results.
Why tables are narrow when tableAutoSize is false, and too wide if true?
It seems to me that if autosize is false, you can't resize the columns anymore.

Comment: Make sure to modify your html code before passing it to html-to-pdfmake. Otherwise I don't know.

Comment: Aymeric, my comment (here is a part of what is transmitted to html-to-pdfmake:) in private mail because it's too long here.

Comment: Note: an A4 page with PDFMake margins has a maximum width of 515.28pt. However your table is 134.65×4 = 538.6pt, so your table will be too large for a A4 page... You'll have to either reduce the table's width (in your code you can test if you table is larger than 515) or change the default PDFMake margins.